# C# visual studio how to change .exe.config file name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, configuration-files

i have some winform solution in VS2012 Pro. How can i change default .config file for main executable ofmy project? ive change project assembly name and now it do not see variables from .config file couse .config is generated with old project assembly name.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Name from the properties.

Right Click on project -> Click on properties ->  And there is one tab with name application Click on that. You will find two text box one for AssemblyName (Change this to CRM)

After that your exe name will be CRM.exe.